# How does this return statement with multiple values (variables) works?

Tags: c, function

I am trying to get some understanding about how pass by value & return are happening in C functions. I cam across a piece of code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int ii, int jj)
{
 int kk, ll;
 kk = ii + jj;
 ll = ii * jj;
 return (kk,ll);
}

int main()
{
 int i=4, j=5, k, l;
 k = fun(i, j);
 l = fun(i, j);
 printf("%d %d\n", k, l);
 return 0;
}
```

Now apparently I am not getting any errors when I am trying to return 2 values through `fun()`.

Also, the value that is returned by `fun()` is `ll` i.e 20 (=4*5) and not `kk`. Further, If I rewrite the `return` statement as :

```
return (ll,kk);
```

the value returned is that of `kk` ie. 9 (=4+5).

**Query**: Why this is so?

Comment: Out of interest, what did you _expect_ to happen?

Comment: @Useless maybe, a compiler error. To quote OP _"Now apparently I am not getting any errors"_:-)

Comment: Actually yes. An error message of sorts. Like trying to pass return more than 1 value etc.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, in the `return` statement

```
 return (kk,ll);
```

you're using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). By the property of the comma operator, you're not returning two values, rather you're returning the second operand of the comma operator only.

To elaborate, let's check the property of the comma operator, directly quoting the standard, `C11`, chapter §6.5.17, (*emphasis mine*)

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; **the result has its type and value.**

So, essentially, a return statement like

```
 return (kk,ll);
```

is same as

```
return ll;
```

Hope you can figure out the other case.

---

That said, the recommended signature for `main()` is `int main(int argc, char*argv[])` or , at least, `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect when returning an int? C does not support tuples.

You are using the [comma-operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.17). `(ll, kk)` is a single expression with the inner expressions (seperated by `,` - thus the name) being evaluated left to right. All but the rightmost (you can have more than two sub-expressions) results are discarded and the rightmost result is the result of the whole expression. Actually the parenthesis are unnecessary and do not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

> The comma operator (represented by the token `,`) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).