# How does return works with multiple variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, return

Hi I am new to javascript. I am looking at big javascript code already working fine. It contains following statements :

```
function(a){
  return this.prt = a,this;
}
```

and in the client code, they are using it as

```
obj.a(34).a(54)
```

I want to know what's happening here ? Does javascript allows returning of multiple values.

Pardoning for may be such a silly question. I have googled out, but couldn't find any good references.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at this post [How does this return statement with multiple values (variables) works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810832/how-does-this-return-statement-with-multiple-values-variables-works). However, it's for c language, but I think the rule for comma operator applier here also. Thus, return a,b will result into evaluation of a and then b and returning result of b's evaluation.

Comment: That's correct. In your example, it's evaluating `this.prt = a` (i.e. assigning the value of `a` to `this.prt`), then it's evaluating `this`, and the result of the entire expression is the last thing evaluated, `this`, which is then returned.

Answer (score 2):

I tried running these lines of code on console.

```
this.name = "yasser";
function demo(){
    return this.name = "neel", 10;
}
```

And here is what I got,

this.name evaluates to 'neel' and 
demo() fn returns 10.

So no you cannot return multiple values from javascript. You can return multiple values combining them into one object.